# How to properly upgrade npm on debian when installed with apt

Tags: node.js, npm, debian, apt

I have issue with jessie and npm.

I have installed package nodejs with `sudo apt-get install nodejs`, so it installed npm automatically.

I then want to install latest of npm using `npm i -g npm@latest`, which work fine except the apt npm version is conflicting.

I want to remove the conflicting apt installed version, or to know the official way to update npm, if installed from apt.

I am only able to update node using `npm i -g n`  then `n stable` but it is impossible for me to upgrade npm

Comment: Did you try it with `sudo npm i -g npm@latest` ?

Comment: Just remove nodejs package. Better to choose either the system one, or your npm and not to mix things.

Comment: @DomeTune no I did not, I have correctly configured npm not to use sudo with `-g`.

Comment: @Giacomo, if I remove the system one, from where do I install npm/nodejs ? In our procedure should we concider installed the apt one and then remove them ? Will it not remove packages installed with `-g` at the same time ?

Comment: see [Installation instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions)

Comment: Check npm documentation, on how to install properly (from scratch). You need to install it, and then you can upgrade. Do no mix the two installations!

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi this is official installation instruction for debian: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions , so now official upgrade command for npm is not working properly.

Comment: You continue mixing things. You can eitherinstall officially as Debian package (your link is about "packages"), or you install stand alone. You want to control which version you want, so you should use this last method. Do no mix packages (and system) with your local preferences!

Answer (score 6):

npm is distributed with Node.js- which means that when you download **Node.js, you automatically get npm installed on your computer**.

A quote from [The npm Blog](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/85484771375/how-to-install-npm)

> The best way to install npm is to install node using the node.js installer. `npm` is installed as part of node.

It’s over at [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/). It will give you a recent, working version of npm with all the paths in the expected places. This is the version that npm Inc and the Node.js project both support.

Once you’ve installed Node.js, you can make sure you’ve got the very most recent version of `npm` using `npm` itself by running this:

```
npm install npm -g
```

If you have issues, do not use `sudo`, read in documentation [fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) carefully and configure `npm` properly.

Comment: It seems from your link that there is no official version for **debian**. So the favorite way for debian users is to completely reinstall from .targ.gz and never use again apt for installing node?

Comment: What about these [official instruction](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) for debian telling you to use `apt` ?

Comment: you should not have to use sudo when using `-g`, you should reconfigure your system properly, see [Fixing Npm Permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)